# QPixmap - How to repeat pixmap, when size is bigger than source image

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap

I was investigating Qt docs regarding `QPixmap` how to set image pixmap properly (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#scaled, etc.).

I was experimenting with different kinds of setting pixmap to a `QGraphicItem` but none of them seemed natural:

[image]

Using the following line of code (and its parameters variations), but I was not able to get results I want:

```
this->mPixmap = QPixmap(path).scaled(mRect.width(), mRect.height(), Qt::KeepAspectRatioByExpanding);
```

Is there any way I can set pixmap so it would be "repeated" on the object with kept aspect ratio, so it would look n the item like this?

[image]

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: Use the `QPixmap` to create a [`QBrush`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbrush.html#QBrush-6)?

Comment: Wow, so simple and works really nicely @G.M - though its also repeated on the Y coordinate. Is there a way to scale it so it matches item height, and after that repeat it on the X coord?

Comment: Don't think so, unfortunately.  Your best bet is probably to scale the height manually as required (possibly using and then use the height-scaled pixmap to create the brush.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, based on G.M. commentary:

```
painter->setBrush(QPixmap(":/img/conv.png").scaledToHeight(mRect.height()));
painter->setBrushOrigin(mRect.topLeft().x(), mRect.topLeft().y());
painter->drawRect(mRect);
```

And it does exactly what I needed:

[image: result]